# Roman pagenumbering on top with horizontal lines

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment, page-numbering, roman

I have the problem that I would like to have Roman and Arabic pagenumbering on top right with a horizontal line below.

However, if I use this package:

```
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
```

with this code:

```
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\headmark}
\ohead*{\pagemark}
```

The horizontal line ap[image]pears **only for the Arabic** page numberings. Does anybody know how to create the line for the Roman page numbers as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunaly there is no MWE (minimal working example) in the question and I do not know which document class is used.

Do not load both packages `fancyhdr` and `scrlayer-scrpage` in a document. If you decide to use `scrlayer-scrpage`, remove all the `fancyhdr` stuff.

If the line below the header (`headsepline`) should be used with both page styles `plain` (by default used on chapter pages) and `scrheadings`, set the options `headsepline` and `plainheadsepline`.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text
\usepackage[headsepline,plainheadsepline,automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\headmark}
\ohead*{\pagemark}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{Foo}
\lipsum[1-10]
\begin{figure}%
\rule{\textwidth}{.5cm}
\caption{This is a sample figure}%
\end{figure}
\lipsum
\begin{figure}%
\rule{\textwidth}{.5cm}
\caption{G.O.A.T.}%
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]